# .js and .css files sometimes not loading/getting to IIS6

Tags: iis-6

I was looking for an answer in the forums but i didnt find one, so i'll just ask it and hopefully some1 will know the answer to this, coz it's a very tricky situation:

When i put 2 new definitions in the IIS6 extentions: .js and .css, with "v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll"  and I take the V off verify file exists, i get a weird response when entering the site.

Lets say i have 5 JS and 5 CSS files, everytime i enter the site some files will not get loaded, and it's totally random, at one time 1 js will not loaded, another time 2 different css will not load, it's just really random.
IIS logs doesn't show the missing JS, meaning it didnt even get to the IIS from what i understand...
when i look through a sniffer i see that the site is calling the file with GET as it should, and it doesn't recieve anything and it just continues to load the other files.

If i take the extentions off then everything is wroking, and loading properly.

Please help me, i'm going crazy!!!

Answer (score 0):

just a quick additional information, i'm using .net 3.5 sp1

i'm kinda sure it's a .net issue, beacuse without the extentions the request does reach and when i put the extentions it doesnt...